# Python ConfigParser - need quotes for string values

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am using Python ConfigParser to create a config file like this:

```
MIN=1
MAX=3
DAYS=2

COLUMN_NAME=Team ID
NAME=First Last
```

This file needs to be consumed within Python, and also a separate proprietary C library. The C lib expects any strings that contain space to be surrounded by quotes ("). Like this

```
COLUMN_NAME="Team ID"
NAME="First Last"
```

I was looking for some standard way to do this but couldn't find any. The best I could come up with is:

```
config['Team'] = {'COLUMN_NAME': '"'+myVariable+'"',
                  'NAME': '"'+myVar2+'"'}
```

It doesn't seem very elegant. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: No support for that in `ConfigParser`. You'll have to write the file manually.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.7, you're able to use f-strings to format things a bit more elegantly:

```
config['Team'] = {'COLUMN_NAME': f'"{myVariable}"',
                  'NAME': f'"{myVar2}"'}
```

Essentially, add an 'f' before your outermost quotation marks (' '), surround your variables with curly brackets ({ }), and then surround the curly-bracketed variables with the double quotation marks (" ") you want.

Read more about f-strings here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

Hope this helps.